# A script works in browser if I input it string by string. But it doesn't work on a real web site

Tags: javascript

My code (draft):

```
function get_city(){
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url='https://api.sypexgeo.net/json/';
    http.open("GET", url);
    http.send();
    console.log("Resp: " + http.responseText);
    var response_json = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    return response_json["city"]["name_en"];
}
```

Could you help me understand why this script is not working on a real web site.

I mean that I can enter each string from this script into a browser's console and get a correct result.

But as soon as I try to use it on a real website, I get this error:

```
Resp: 
VM350:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at get_city (?utm_replace=ViarVizualizatorArhiva_TR:588)
    at replacer (?utm_replace=ViarVizualizatorArhiva_TR:637)
    at ?utm_replace=ViarVizualizatorArhiva_TR:647
```

As we can see, response is empty. Well, this is a mystery to me. Why should it be empty if in console it is ok?

Comment: You're using an asynchronous API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous protocol call. Your code keeps going after your `.send()` action, but your response could come later, or never.

You need to perform your action only when the response is received.

After your `send()` action, wrap your code in an event handler:

```
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    //your response handler
}
```

See: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa